# Singleton Overlaps?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I have two classes using as singletons.

```
class Boss {
    static let sharedInstance = Boss()
    private init() {} 

    var user_id : String?
    var username : String?
}



class Job {
    static let sharedInstance = Job()
    private init() {} 

    var job_id : String?
    var JobType : String?
}
```

But after populating the `Boss.sharedInstance` first, `Job.sharedInstance` also containing Boss' class variables. But after replacing the `sharedInstance` with other name (for eg. `job_sharedInstance` and `boss_sharedInstance`) respectively, things are working fine. It's quite weird. Can anybody explain me the reason why it would happen like this. Thanks in advance.

Here is the breakpoint. Although `Job.sharedInstance` does not have `user_id, username, etc...`, it's showing up.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a (short) *full* example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"Job.sharedInstance also containing Boss' class variables"* ?

Comment: @MartinR please check my edited question. I put a screenshot.

Comment: This is a bug in the debugger view. When in doubt, *print* values or inspect them in the debugger console.

Comment: @MartinR oh yeah, it's true. The weird thing is if I change name of `sharedInstance`, it also correct the debugger view.

Comment: Being weird is a property of many bugs :)

Comment: @MartinR haha, true, Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with your code. Both `Boss` and `Job`
have a `static let sharedInstance` property, and these are
completely independent of each other. Different classes
*can* have static properties with the same name,
and these don't "overlap".

If the debugger shows properties for `Job.sharedInstance`
which are not even defined in the `Job` class then this is
a *bug* in the debugger view.

When in doubt, add `print` statements to your code.